# Refresh data in table after creating a record

Tags: javascript, sapui5, crud, page-refresh

In  my Ui5 app I have added CREATE operation using oData. But when i am trying to create entry it is getting added in backend but in table it is showing NO DATA (refer image 1). but when I refresh the same page it is there (refer image 2). With single entry ,it is automatically getting refreshed 
problem is with Multiple entries.

Please refer the screenshot and code for clear view.

After Clicking CREATE button:

[image]

After Refreshing WebPage:

[image]

```js
onCreate: function() {
  var oModel = this.getView().getModel();

  var contactEntry1 = {
      ProductID: 'KT-1960',
      TypeCode: 'AD',
      SupplierID: '0100000001',
      TaxTarifCode: 1,
      Category: 'Notebooks',
      MeasureUnit: 'EA',
      CurrencyCode: 'EUR',
      Name: 'Urvish',
      Description: 'First batch entry',
    },

    contactEntry2 = {
      ProductID: 'KT-1982',
      TypeCode: 'AD',
      SupplierID: '0100000001',
      TaxTarifCode: 1,
      Category: 'Notebooks',
      MeasureUnit: 'EA',
      CurrencyCode: 'EUR',
      Name: 'Urvish',
      Description: 'Second batch entry',
    };

  oModel.setUseBatch(true);
  oModel.create('/ProductSet', contactEntry1);
  oModel.create('/ProductSet', contactEntry2);


  oModel.refresh(true);


},
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that you use the asynchronous operation for **create** but think that they are synchronous.

In order to fix this out, you can send these 2 **create** in one `$batch` request, but use the `createEntry` method of `ODataModel`, in order to use the `submitChanges` method, the callback of which, will be called once two of items are successfully created on the backend side (the below code example should be relevant for `v2.ODataModel`):

```js
var oTableItemsBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");

// define the group ID, which will be used later on
var aCurrentDeferredGroups = oModel.getDeferredGroups();
oModel.setDeferredGroups(aCurrentDeferredGroups.concat("createProductGroup"));

// create two entries one by one, specifying the 'groupId' parameter
oModel.createEntry("/ProductSet", {
    properties: contactEntry1,
    groupId: "createProductGroup"
});

oModel.createEntry("/ProductSet", {
    properties: contactEntry2,
    groupId: "createProductGroup"
});

// send 2 requests in one $batch, passing the name of the 'groupId'
oModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: "createProductGroup",
    success: function() {
      // no need to call refresh() as the model already does it by default (See "refreshAfterChange")
    }.bind(this)
});
```

If your service does not support `$batch` requests, then you can still use the `create` method, but make use of it's **success** callback to be sure that the entry has been persisted in the backend.